# Order of the natural numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, definition, peano-axioms

The set of natural numbers as given from the Peano axioms $(N,S)$ has an order.

I saw in wikipedia that $(N,+)$ is a commutative monoid, but since the naturals  have an order structure by construction shouldn't  $(N,+)$ be an ordered commutative monoid ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it is indeed.

Comment: Are you asking this because you think it is mandatory that every set be described by all appellations it has for every structure it has? Then it is also a commutative, ordered semiring. And probably 57 other things. Saying it *is* one thing does not mean it *isn't* anything else.

Comment: Did you run across a source that said it *wasn't* an ordered commutative monoid?

Comment: A dolphin is a carnivorous marine mammal.  Is it wrong to say it is a marine mammal?  Not completely saying something is what it is is not wrong.  Saying something is what it is not is wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have a square and call it a rectangle. There is no inherent problem with that, as long as all you really need from your quadrilateral is that all angles are right.

In the exact same way, you can take an ordered, commutative monoid and call it a commutative monoid.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, your example made it very clear!!

Comment: Why, as a Math major Arthur, and computer programmer of twenty years (who knows what Haskell and LISP are) is this language of category theory (I think), so opaque to me as to its function? Set theory and Axiom of Choice are pretty much where I draw the line lol..

Comment: So can i say: 1. $N$ is a set (True) 2. A set has no structure (True). Therefore $N$    has no structure. But $N$ has structure!

Comment: @kot 2. A set does not necessarily have structure.  It may have structure arising from some other source.  Euclidean space has a huge amount of structure (as a metrizable vector space).  But we can also just think of it as a set.  In fact, a number of definitions can be phrased: "[term] is a set that also satisfies the following properties ..."

Comment: @Teepeem So one can think of  Euclidean space only as a set therefore without structure or one should not think of Euclidean space only as a set ?

Comment: @kot It depends on what you're doing.  If I say, "consider the field of real numbers", then what comes next should use the field aspect somehow.  In your original post, if someone says "consider $(N,+)$ as an ordered commutative monoid", I would expect their argument to use each of those aspects (otherwise, why bother mentioning it?).  But a longer discussion should probably go to a new question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but you can discuss addition without discussing order.

The same way that you can say that $(\mathbb R,+)$ is a group. It is also an abelian group. It is a ring. It is a field. It is an ordered field. It is a module over $\mathbb Z$. Etc., etc.

Comment: On a somewhat related note : if there are exactly two cows on a picture, is it mathematically correct to say that there is one cow on the picture?

Comment: Of course. Otherwise, the sentence "the set of natural numbers contains a natural number" would be false :)

Comment: Related: is it true that there are finitely many prime numbers?  Yes.  (But it is not true that there are **only** finitely many prime numbers.)

Answer (score 4):

$(N,+)$ is both a commutative monoid and an ordered commutative monoid.